# JavaFX: Custom window with native behavior

Tags: java, wpf, windows, javafx, window

I like to have a fully customized Window in JavaFX. Exactly the same problem as here:

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WPF-styling-a-Window-in-fcf4e4ce

Using an UNDECORATED JavaFX stage, I have to implement all window functionality on my own - and lose all native window behavior, including:

- Maximize when dragged to the top
- Side-by-Side view when dragged to the sides
- Minimizing/Maximizing when clicking taskbar

Can I somehow access the native Windows API to implement these functionalities?
Or do you have any other ideas?

Please do not recommend Undecorator, it does not meet my requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

4 years later, following [Custom Window Frame Using DWM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dwm/customframe) and dealing with some JavaFX issues, I was able to implement this in what I published as [fxstage](https://github.com/micheljung/fxstage).