# How can I can get the native window handle from JavaFX Stage?

Tags: javafx

How can I can get the native window handle from JavaFX Stage?
JavaFX Version is 16. Java Version is 11.
The window handle is HWND(Windows) or XWindow(X11).

Comment: why? Afaik, there is no public api to access the handle. You can try digging in internals: Window has a package-private method getPeer (accessible via reflection) which returns an internal class TKStage (needs add-exports at compiletime and add-opens at runtime) with a method getRawHandle

Comment: alternatively (replacing the reflection in the first step) you can use the internal class WindowHelper to access a window's peer

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37454818/javafx-custom-window-with-native-behavior (answered)

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/micheljung/fxstage

```
FxStage.configure(stage).apply();
```

[image]